# DataBinding and UpdateSourceTrigger on Content

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

Okay, so I've been attempting to learn a bit of MVVM. It's been only three days and have come to a dead end. The application simply retrieves the client's external ip address and updates the new ip address in a label found in my UI. However, rather than just going the old-fashioned way of simply doing,

```
ipAdd.Content = getNewIp();
```

and ending the story end there. Rather, I decided to use some MVVM to achieve the following:

- Retrieve ip address, then display it to the user in a label
- Query the database and update the user's ip address
- Rinse, repeat every five minutes.

The reason I chose to go more MVVM is to use `UpdateSourceTrigger` and `UpdateCommand`. Essentially, when the ip address gets updated, I want to do something with it (as mentioned above). I've seen in many tutorials where `UpdateCommand` is used on buttons and `UpdateSourceTrigger` used on input boxes, but nothing that shows how to do it with labels, yet it seems that it should be tied in to the same concept; it might not be explicity a button that is being clicked, but some back code that executes and performs the same task as a button. For starters, here's what I have so far:

**Model**

```
namespace IPdevices
{
    class IP : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _add;
        public string add
        {
            get
            {
                return _add;
            }
            set
            {
                _add = value;
                OnPropertyChange("add");
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
namespace IPdevices
{
    class IPViewModel
    {
        private IP _ip;

        public IPViewModel()
        {
            UpdateCommand = new IPUpdateCommand(this);
        }


        public ICommand UpdateCommand
        {
            get; private set;
        }

        public bool CanUpdate
        {
            get
            {
                return true; // just say yes for now
            }
        }

        public IP IP
        {
            get
            {
                return _ip;
            }
            set
            {
                _ip = value;
            }
        }

        public void updateClientIp()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("_updating client ip and query database");
        }
    }
}
```

**ICommand**

```
namespace IPdevices
{
    class IPUpdateCommand : ICommand
    {
        private IPViewModel _viewModel;
        public IPUpdateCommand(IPViewModel vm)
        {
            _viewModel = vm;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _viewModel.CanUpdate;
        }


        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _viewModel.updateClientIp();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow**

```
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ipAdd.DataContext = new IPViewModel();
}
```

**View**

```
<Label x:Name="ipAdd" Content="{Binding Path=IP.add}"/>
```

What I'm trying to achieve here can easily be done without going MVVM (perhaps overkill as well) and simply calling a few helper classes to update the user's ip on the db side, but for the sake of getting used to doing things MVVM, I tried incorporating the way I did, though with no luck.

Is there any way to do this, or even better, should it be done this way?

Comment: I'm trying to identify any state where `IPViewModel.IP` is not `null`; am I missing something? Why isn't your viewmodel implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Why is `IP` a separate class? Why is `IP.add` called `add`? What does that mean? Why have a whole viewmodel just for one Label?

Comment: IP.add is the string that contains the ip address. Perhaps I can make it more verbose. Shouldn't the model be implementing INotifyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: Viewmodels implement INotifyPropertyChang‌​ed; models don't. Why does the `IP` class even exist?

Comment: What would the model be in this case? IP class was made solely to tie in the "model" in there somewhere; it was almost forced...

Comment: A model is a bare representation of something -- a POCO class type of thing. A viewmodel has INotifyPropertyChanged, commands, etc. It exposes stuff that allows interaction between UI and data. A VM often duplicates all the properties of the model, but its properties raise PropertyChanged.  So you get a model from a DB, copy its properties to a VM, user changes stuff in UI. Is it dirty? Compare VM to model, property by property. If dirty, prompt user to save to DB. If user wants ot cancel changes, copy "clean" model properties to VM again. That kind of thing.

Comment: Simpler applications may not have any need for a model. In any case, I would either make `IPViewModel.IP` a String, or make it `System.Net.IPAddress` and write a value converter

Comment: "Viewmodels implement INotifyPropertyChang‌​‌ed; models don't". I wouldn't take that too serious. If you have a situation where it would make sense that a model class implements INotifyPropertyChang‌​‌ed, just implement it that way. There is no strict rule. E.g. if you generate a web service client class by svcutil (which imo is a model class), it will typically implement INotifyPropertyChang‌​‌ed.

Comment: This is where I get confused, I've seen people call `OnPropertyChange` within their model classes, which would imply that the model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Why would we re-write the same properties in the viewmodel? It's almost redundant. In my situation, I really did not need a model since the data in question, is simply a string. So I guess it would make sense to leave it in the ViewModel...?

Comment: You may e.g. derive your view model class from your model class and add commands and additional view-related properties. Again, there is no strict rule.

Comment: @Clemens No strict rule, just a rough rule of thumb. Dmitri -- I don't see any need for a model in what you've got here. And with a learning exercise, I'd recommend starting off simple, just viewmodel and view.

Comment: @EdPlunkett looks like I got my work cut out for me!

Comment: @EdPlunkett I managed to get it to work by putting a simple string in the view model. However, The commands can only fired through the use of some sort of button where you would bind the command in the Command part of the button. Is there a way to do this without a button? This comes back to the original problem I had: if the property changed in the label, how can I fire a command?

Comment: Can you give me a one-comment-long description of what you want this application to do?

Comment: Simple: retrieve ip address (which works), query db (insert record into db), display ip to user (through a label). What's happening right now, is the label is being updated with the new ip, but I need to trigger an event in order to insert record in db. Usually, I you can bind a command to do so within a button, but there is no button that exists; just a label, hence why I was interested in the OnPropertyChange.

Comment: So you run it, it does this stuff, and that's it?

Comment: @EdPlunkett only for now. Our team made this application in WinForms originally. In essence, we're starting a hosting service, DNS management, etc for clients with dynamic IP addresses. We decided to migrate to WPF given its flexibility. For now, this is unfamiliar ground and what I just described in my previous comment is just to get familiarized and learn to work with MVVM and WPF...

Comment: OK, never mind that question. In this case, I would have a viewmodel that finds out what the IP address is, and "exposes" that via a public property that raises `PropertyChanged` in its setter. I would have a view with a Label that displays that `IP` property. I would then write a method in the viewmodel that gets the IP address, writes it to the database, and updates `IP`. I might expose a command to call that method; I might have a BackgroundWorker that calls that method every `n` minutes. I would have it check the newly retrieved ip addr against `IP`, and only save to DB if it changed.

Comment: I would never consider writing to the DB in response to changes to the Label, because the Label merely displays the state "published" by the viewmodel. The viewmodel is the "engine" or "brain" in MVVM. It drives things. The UI exists to allow the viewmodel to communicate with the user, and if necessary, for the user to communicate back. If I had an UpdateIP command, that would be to allow the user to manually refresh the IP by clicking a button. No button requirement, no need for a command.

Comment: Ohhhh, `add` is for "address"; sorry, I'm thick sometimes!

Comment: I think you were the one helping me out a couple of days ago. Right now, the ip gets refreshed every 5 mins using async + Task and dispatch timer. I have a separate class that retrieves ip (does some txt logging) and once it is found, it throws it in the label. So it wouldn't make sense to update db in the OnPropertyChanged method?

Comment: Ah OK, I would have the viewmodel own the instance of the async IP polling class, and IP poller class would have an event that it raises every time it retrieves the IP address. The viewmodel would subscribe to that event when it creates and initializes the poller. In the handler it would check to see if the new address is different from the old address, then if it is, update the `IP` property and write to the database.

Comment: Oh okay, makes sense. I think this calls for an Observer pattern with some form of notification of when ip gets updated. Checking against old and new ip could be done somewhere in there.

Comment: "but nothing that shows how to do it with labels" is correct, sourcetrigger fires when the _User_ updates a control. A User cannot update a label.